# Process webserver log data and using Kafka for messaging and KSQL for processing

Tags: ksqldb

I am trying to find the position of a substring from main string but i did not get any function in Ksql db, could any one please suggest me any function is available to find the position.

```
3/11/20 1:32:02 PM CDT, 00005, {"value":" 472 Dynamic 11 SQL 0 Start=2020/03/11 05:51:05.730 MOdelName: SELECT DISTINCT "TIME_DIM".YEAR_DESC, "TIME_DIM".LEVEL1_KEY FROM "TEST_TIME_DIM" WHERE (("TIME_DIM".HIER_FLAG_TEST = 59) AND ("TIME_DIM".LEVEL1_KEY = "TIME_DIM".UNIFORM_KEY_TEST) AND ("TIME_DIM".LEVEL2_KEY_TEST IS NULL) AND ("TIME_DIM".LEVEL3_KEY_TEST IS NULL) AND ("TIME_DIM".LEVEL5_KEY_TEST IS NULL)) ORDER BY "TIME_DIM".YEAR_DESC_TEST ASC, "TIME_DIM".LEVEL1_KEY_TEST ASC [nodeid=1]"}
```

in above message i want to extract entire sql , and trying to find the position of character "SQL" so that based on the position i can extract the sql.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a sample input message and an example of what you're trying to extract from it?

Comment: sample Message:
3/11/20 1:32:02 PM CDT,   00005, {"value":" 472  Dynamic 11      SQL 0   Start=2020/03/11 05:51:05.730   MOdelName: SELECT DISTINCT "TIME_DIM".YEAR_DESC, "TIME_DIM".LEVEL1_KEY FROM "TEST_TIME_DIM" WHERE (("TIME_DIM".HIER_FLAG_TEST = 59) AND ("TIME_DIM".LEVEL1_KEY = "TIME_DIM".UNIFORM_KEY_TEST) AND ("TIME_DIM".LEVEL2_KEY_TEST IS NULL) AND ("TIME_DIM".LEVEL3_KEY_TEST IS NULL) AND ("TIME_DIM".LEVEL5_KEY_TEST IS NULL)) ORDER BY "TIME_DIM".YEAR_DESC_TEST ASC, "TIME_DIM".LEVEL1_KEY_TEST ASC     [nodeid=1]"}

Comment: in above message i want to extract entire sql , and trying to find the position of character "SQL" so that based on the position i can extract the sql.

Comment: I've edited your question to include this info - best if you put it all in the question instead of comments to make it easier for people to follow.

Comment: So your data has a single field called `value` and you want just the statement starting `SELECT DISTINCT "TIME_DIM[…]` and ending `[…]LEVEL1_KEY_TEST ASC`, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is one example.

Comment: Hi, can any one plz tell me the solution for above problem.

Comment: It's a weird data structure you've got. Maybe https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/4728 will help, once ksqlDB 0.8 drops.

Answer (score 0):

[INSTR](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#instr) will find the position of a substring in a string.

[SUBSTRING](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#substring) will allow you to extract a substring, based on position.